# Get the next date relative to today from calendar table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an Outlook calendar with regular maintenance events. I'd like to show the next upcoming maintenance date in a Power BI dashboard.

I've managed to get the events from the Outlook calendar into a table that's available in Power BI Desktop.

[image]

But I'm not expert in DAX or Power BI enough to figure out how to get the next event date (currently, I'd like to show the 28 Jan 2024 event).

I tried `nextMaintenanceDate = MAX('Calendar (2)'[Start])` but obviously this will select the 'biggest' one, i.e., the onie in February. :-/

Another thing I'd like to show is the number of days until the next maintenance event ('25 days until next Maintenance'). I guess this should be a simple subtraction of the `nextMaintenanceDate` and `TODAY()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to filter your table first to return all dates from today onwards, then get the earliest date. Try this measure:

```
nextMaintenanceDate =
  CALCULATE(
    MIN('Calendar (2)'[Start]),
    'Calendar (2)'[Start] >= TODAY()
  )
```

And correct on your days until next one - wrap it in an `INT` to get an integer:

```
nextMaintenanceDays = INT( [nextMaintenanceDate] - TODAY() )
```